# How to use CSS when installed from npm in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack

I am trying to install the below:

```
npm install bootstrap-material-design
```

I then added the below to my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "bootstrap-material-design": "0.5.10"
}
```

So in angular2 using webpack, how do I import?  The docs for the package say the below and the package was installed in `node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/`:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Material Design -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/ripples.min.css">
```

So in the head do I include via the below:

```
 <!-- Bootstrap Material Design -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/ripples.min.css">
```

Or will angular2 already include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better you include in your main module file like in `app.ts` file:

```
// Just make sure you use the relative path here
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css'
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/ripples.min.css'

// your component (example code below)

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.template.html'
})
```

And that's it. Webpack will take care of the reset.

**Edit:**

If you have created the app using `angular-cli/ng-cli` then you can also include these stylesheets to `angular-cli.json`

Comment: I assume that same logic goes with jquery too?

Comment: yup, correct. You can do the same with jQuery as well.